# Call selector from a component and pass content via content projection in Angular 12+

Tags: angular

I want to load selector  from a component and pass content in that selector from another component.

I am new to angular and i do not know what to implement. Any concept will help me.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Please read [ask], and more explain your issue and where you are stuck. You can also make the [tour] or add a [mre] into your post

Comment: angular provide content projection when content is provided inside the selector tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in **app.module.ts** register the apple component in **declaration** array.

file name : **apple.component.ts**

```html
<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <h2>I am from apple component</h2>
  <h3>Angular</h3>
  <h4>JavaScript & TypeScript</h4>
  <h5>HTML & CSS</h5>

  <!-- class ng-content project is used -->
  <ng-content select=".extra"></ng-content>
</ng-template>

<!-- enable template to show/execute -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
```

file name : **app.component.ts**

```html
<!-- with content project (same selector : app-apple) -->
<app-apple>
  <h4 class="extra">SOME EXTRA CONTENT THROUGH CONTENT PROJECTION</h4>
</app-apple>

<hr>

<!-- without content project (same selector : app-apple) -->
<app-apple></app-apple>
```